# Encrypting full word using Paillier Scheme

Tags: encryption, paillier

I am using Paillier scheme to encrypt a message however, I have divided the words into alphabets and then convert each alphabet to ASCII code encrypting the final result. It works fine, but I want to encrypt each word. It this possible?

As by encrypting each alphabet the size of encrypted file increases 10 times.

Comment: Think about how SSL/TLS encrypt whole session.

Answer (score 3):

In the most common variant of Paillier encryption with public modulus $n$, any plaintext in $[0,n)$ can be encrypted and decrypted (though sometime the interval is slightly reduced, or centered on zero). To be secure, Pailler encryption needs $n$ to have unknown factorization. That means like at least 1024-bit $n$ (with 2048-bit or more highly recommendable). That allows encrypting 127 (or 255) bytes. That's more than enough for UTF-8 encoding of any word in an English or French dictionary (I have no idea for others).

If encrypting character by character with Paillier encryption increases size by 10 only, then $n$ is at most 40-bit, and the encryption is thus not secure.

It's unusual to use Paillier encryption on text: it's primarily used when it's homomorphic property is useful. For text, practice is [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hybrid_encryption), which allows arbitrary large plaintext.

Comment: [Longest French word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_French) is quite short, 36, and interestingly ( for me ) French has not long words compared to others, [English on the other end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English) have some strange results like [protein titin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titin) is [the longest](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Protologisms/Long_words/Titin). Apart from 2 chemical name and a fictional name, all falls in below 46. German is out of the league and Turkish is strange on this subject; recursive suffixes :)